# SonarQube reports duplicate code for same method call with different argument

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a simple java class in which I have to trim string fields, for which I have created a utility method. However when it goes through `SonarQube`, it reports `1 duplicated blocks of code must be removed` in the class.

What's wrong with this code

[image: duplicate code]

Comment: Are you sure that you quote the relevant part of the reported issue ?

Comment: Yes, this class has more similar methods, they're also highlighted same way. In some other classes I have used something like `CommonUtil.trim(...)` in `getters`, nothing is highlighted there, but it shows the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Well that turned out to be a whole lot of nothing. Duplication report is shown because same methods are present in another class. There's no reference to the name other class where the duplication was found.

After creating a generic class with these method, issue goes away.